# Given a plot of a network Graph[] how can the {x,y} screen coordinates be output?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is there a general way to get the screen or "world" coordinates for every vertex in the graphic output of something like this?

```
Table[Graph[Table[i \[UndirectedEdge] i + 1, {i, 20}], 
  GraphLayout -> l, 
  PlotLabel -> l], 
{l, {"CircularEmbedding", "SpiralEmbedding"}}]
```

Trying to build an algorithm to generate novel layouts and want to use a large amount of other algorithms for training data.

Comment: does `GraphEmbedding` give what you need?  I.e., `graphs = Table[
  Graph[Table[i \[UndirectedEdge] i + 1, {i, 20}], GraphLayout -> l,  PlotLabel -> l], {l, {"CircularEmbedding", 
    "SpiralEmbedding"}}]; GraphEmbedding /@ graphs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
el=Table[i <-> i + 1, {i, 20}];
graphs = Table[Graph[el, GraphLayout -> l, PlotLabel -> l], 
  {l, {"CircularEmbedding", "SpiralEmbedding"}}];
```

You can use [`GraphEmbedding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphEmbedding.html) to get the vertex coordinates:

```
vcs = GraphEmbedding /@ graphs
```

> ```
> {{{-0.294755, 0.955573}, {-0.56332, 0.826239}, {-0.781831,  0.62349},
> ```

```
   {-0.930874, 0.365341}, {-0.997204, 0.0747301}, {-0.974928, -0.222521}, 
   {-0.866025, -0.5}, {-0.680173, -0.733052}, {-0.433884, -0.900969}, 
   {-0.149042, -0.988831}, {0.149042, -0.988831}, {0.433884, -0.900969}, 
   {0.680173, -0.733052}, {0.866025, -0.5}, {0.974928, -0.222521}, 
   {0.997204, 0.0747301}, {0.930874, 0.365341}, {0.781831, 0.62349},
   {0.56332,  0.826239}, {0.294755, 0.955573}, {-1.59266*10^-15, 1.}}, 
  {{1.8432, 0.}, {2.63004, 0.18546}, {1.87661, 0.37092}, {0.681386, 0.55638}, 
   {0.527999, 0.74184}, {1.55172, 0.9273}, {2.90492, 1.11276}, 
   {3.60771, 1.29822}, {3.1983, 1.48368}, {1.93929, 1.66914}, 
   {0.601612, 1.8546}, {0., 2.04006}, {0.51861, 2.22552}, {1.85511, 2.41098}, 
   {3.13565, 2.59644}, {3.41725, 2.7819}, {2.40538, 2.96736}, 
   {0.978453, 3.15282}, {0.841183, 3.33828}, {2.35239, 3.52374}, {1.8432, 3.7092}}}
```

You can also get the coordinates directly using the two-argument form of `GraphEmbedding` using `el` as the first argument:

```
vcs2 = Table[GraphEmbedding[el,l], {l, {"CircularEmbedding",   "SpiralEmbedding"}}];
vcs2 == vcs
```

> ```
> True
> ```